# Enterprise provisioning for watchkit app?

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, ios-provisioning

My company is using enterprise distribution profiles to sign our iOS app for easy distribution to in-house and external testers. Everything has been working fine locally and in our CI system, but we recently started working on a WatchKit app, and we can't figure out how to codesign it correctly for enterprise distribution.

We've created app identifiers for the iOS app, the WatchKit extension, and the WatchKit app, as well as an app group. Development provisioning is working fine and we can test the watch app on hardware without issue. However, when trying to sign using our enterprise profiles, everything appears to work but the app will not install on the Apple Watch, showing an "Application could not be verified" error on the watch screen and the following in the console:

> Warning: failed to install WatchKit application, error: (Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x15d6e0d0 {Error=ApplicationVerificationFailed, ErrorDetail=-402620394, ErrorDescription=Failed to verify code signature of [redatcted] : 0xe8008016 (Entitlements found that are not permitted by provisioning profile)})

Is it even possible to use enterprise distribution provisioning profiles to sign a WatchKit app? There doesn't seem to be any documentation about this anywhere I can find, and the error description is of very little help.

Comment: As far as I know, you will need to use the "Apple Store" provisioning profile in order to internal test via Apple version TestFlight. For In-House distribution, it should be the same with the developmental deployment I think.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the WatchKit App and the WatchKit extension targets each need their own enterprise provisioning profile to be explicitly specified in the build settings. Since these have different bundle identifiers, they must be different profiles, since wildcard profiles cannot be used for enterprise distribution anymore.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973011/xcodebuild-different-provisioning-profile-for-target-dependency) has more information about how to specify different profiles from the command line.