# How to build a workspace with frameworks from command line with overridden non-wildcard PROVISIONING_PROFILE

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

My workspace consists of projects with framework targets, and app project which uses these frameworks.

To build workspace with overridden provisioning profile I am using next command:

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos clean build -workspace <workspace-name> 
-scheme <scheme-name> -configuration Release 
PROVISIONING_PROFILE=<profile-uuid>
```

Profile is non-wildcard.

From the Xcode distribution build performs normally.
From command-line, the errors are generated because `xcodebuild` also overrides provisioning profile for frameworks and tries to sign them.

```
Code Sign error: Provisioning profile does not match bundle identifier: 
The provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“<profile-name>”) 
has an AppID of “<profile-app-id>” which does not match your 
bundle identifier “<framework-bundle-id>”.
```

That's strange, because when building from Xcode, after the final app is built, frameworks are re-signed with the app's provisioning profile, and signing of them during the building is not required.

How to avoid this issue?

UPD: Command-line build is performed by plugin on Continuous Integration system which overrides PROVISIONING_PROFILE variable. That's why it is crucial to keep using of that variable, not some user-defined ones. But seems like it's not possible. Xcode performs redundant signing of frameworks first with whatever-matching profile you specified, and then - with the application's provisioning profile when it installs frameworks into bundle, and there is no way to avoid this redundant first signing.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973011/xcodebuild-different-provisioning-profile-for-target-dependency/29605731#29605731

Comment: Updated question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Apple that I've got on reported bug:

> This issue behaves as intended based on the following:
>
> Settings passed on the command-line to xcodebuild will override all
>   instances of that setting across all targets being built. That's how
>   it works.
>
> In order to override only selected targets, you would need to do
>   something tricky in your target set-up, for example:
>
> In the target, assuming the target is named "MyTarget":
>
> PROVISIONING_PROFILE=$(PROVISIONING_PROFILE_$(TARGET_NAME))
>     PROVISIONING_PROFILE_MyTarget=
>
> And then in xcodebuild, you would do:
>
> xcodebuild 
>   PROVISIONING_PROFILE_MyTarget=
>
> If you have multiple targets you need to selectively override then you
>   could do this for each of them, replacing 'MyTarget' in the setting
>   name with the appropriate name for each target.

So currently they would prefer to keep redundant signing of frameworks during the workspace build.