# Xcode 7.2: how to build with Ad Hoc provisioning profile vs. App Store provisioning profile?

Tags: xcode, xcode7, provisioning-profile, xcodebuild, ios-provisioning

Currently in Xcode, I have a Development scheme and an Ad Hoc scheme. Both are set to Automatic under Xcode Project -> iOS app target -> Build Settings -> Provisioning Profile.

I'm currently using xcodebuild from the command line and specifying the Ad Hoc scheme to build my apps.

However, it seems like xcodebuild is performing the codesign with the App Store provisioning profile, instead of the Ad Hoc one.

Is there a way for me to specify which provisioning profile to use? Should I pass in an argument into xcodebuild? I'd prefer to do that, while keeping the Xcode build scheme set to "Automatic."

Comment: Have you tried exporting the archived build as an Ad Hoc build?

Comment: That definitely works, but I'm hoping to be able to select provisioning profiles when building via command line with xcodebuild. An additional complication with that is that I have an iOS app, a Watch app, and extensions for both. So I can't just manually specify one provisioning profile for Ad Hoc.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach I've seen is to specify environment variables for your difference provisioning profiles.  Then, when you build, you can pass in values for the different provisioning profiles for the extension and watch app as well.

You can see the details of this approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29605731/3708242