# Jenkins iOS build error: no such module 'XXX'

Tags: ios, swift, jenkins

i'm trying to Archive my code by Jenkins and CocoaPods.

But build error, it seems the project can find the module generated by CocoaPods.

i use swift to code and the project is build successfully in Xcode

the podfile is like:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do

pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'ObjectMapper'

end
```

the error log in Jenkins is:

```
....
/Users/xxx/.jenkins/jobs/LIFE_iOS/workspace/MyProject/Core/Model/ItemResult.swift:10:8: error: no such module     'ObjectMapper'
import ObjectMapper
       ^

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/xxx/.jenkins/jobs/LIFE_iOS/workspace/MyProject/MGFramework/CustomViews/MartyJunior/MJTableViewTopCell.swift
...
CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(5 failures)
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Once you are done with pod install you should open your Xcode.workspace and build it not the .project. Try it

Comment: thank you for reply, and it does work.
And there is a new error, can you help me to fix it?

` === BUILD TARGET ObjectMapper OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
    Check dependencies
    Code Sign error: Provisioning profile does not match bundle identifier: The provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“xxxxx”) has an AppID of “me.xxx.ios” which does not match your bundle identifier “org.cocoapods.ObjectMapper”.
    ** BUILD FAILED **
    The following build commands failed:
 Check dependencies
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE`

Comment: Please mark below as the answer. And for your second issue, refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973011/xcodebuild-different-provisioning-profile-for-target-dependency/29605731#29605731

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out by @Santosh, opening the workspace is the right thing to do when using the Xcode UI.
As you are probably using `xcodebuild` on the command line (or Jenkins is), instead of specifying a project and a target, you have to run `xcodebuild` with a workspace and a scheme. Just wanted to add this, as you were asking for Jenkins.

So without CocoaPods, you could have done:

`xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -target MyTarget -configuration Release`

Now, with CocoaPods, you have to:

`xcodebuild -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme MyScheme -configuration`

Comment: Thanks, I Got the same error while trying to Build on VSTS. I kept 'configuration' param empty and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Specify the workspace name in the Jenkins Project configuration. Follow Configure > build > Xcode > Advanced XCode build options -> XCode Workspace File. This enabled the jenkins to invoke the xcodebuild with workspace rather than project and that includes the pod dependencies. Make sure you have a build step of type execute shell "/usr/local/bin/pod install" prior to xcode build step.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are done with `pod install`, you should open your `.xcworkspace` and not `.xcodeproj`. Please try it and let me know.