# Can we configure CI for iOS apps with extensions with AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

We are in process of creating CI builds for iOS apps using Azure DevOps.

I am following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode?view=azure-devops), to create build definitions. Could anyone guide me on how to **build iOS apps with extensions in Azure DevOps**

During our research, we did come across Visual Studio app center as an option, are there any other tools or add-ons to achieve the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Building iOS apps with an extension is not supported by default iOS build task provided by Azure DevOps.

The workaround is to create a shell script to build an iOS app by passing the extension app name as a parameter.

Comment: thanks for the code snippet, or at least providing a reference link

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there is not a straight forward way for the iOS application with App extension in Azure. The only way to create CI for such an application is the command line.

1. To make it work you'll have to do a couple of changes in the project that are recommended on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29605731/3611427).
2. Afterward, you'll be able to build and archive the application using `xcodebuild` Docs. because you'll have a variable pointing to each provisioning profile.
3. On your MAC try xocdebuild command in the terminal and note down the full commands to achieve a specific file.
4. Use `CmdLine@2` task in the pipeline with these commands to build, archive & export your IPA.

> Note: I have posted a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/shakaib-arif/c648267883321c0231a771017212f93b) covering the pipeline for such an iOS application.

The full explanation to create a CI for iOS application with App extension within Azure DevOps is shared on a similar thread. Kindly check the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65967010/3611427) I have posted there.

Hopefully, it will work!