# How can we configure CI for the iOS app with App Extensions

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have tried multiple things in Azure DevOps (VSTS) to create CI for the iOS app but turns out that Azure DevOps [doesn't support](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/383129/build-ios-app-with-app-extensions.html) the apps that have App extensions. Is it really the case?

I'm using the [OneSignal Notification Service Extension](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup) in our project which is dependent on the main target. So, when [Xcode task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode?view=azure-devops) tries to sign the app an error occurs related to the build identifiers as the Xcode main target has a **different** build identifier than OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension's build identifier.

> ❌  error: Provisioning profile "MainTargetName" has app ID "com.xyz.-", which does not match the bundle ID "com.xyz.-.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension". (in target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' from project 'ProjectName')

I'm using an [apple certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-apple-certificate?view=azure-devops) task to install the certificates on the Microsoft hosted agent and similarly using the [provisioning profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-apple-provisioning-profile?view=azure-devops) task to install the provisioning profiles. It looks like the **Xcode task** has a ***[limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/12423)*** that it cannot get multiple provisioning profiles so it can cater to those iOS apps with App Extension.

```
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  displayName: 'Install Certificates'
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: '3Certificates.p12'
    certPwd: '$(P12Password)'
    keychain: 'temp'


- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install MainTarget provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'MainTarget.mobileprovision'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install OneSignal provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'OneSignal.mobileprovision'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'CocoaPods install'
  inputs:
    script: |
      cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
      echo "Pod installation"
      pod install
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Xcode Build'
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'CICD.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'CICD'
    xcodeVersion: 'specifyPath'
    xcodeDeveloperDir: '/Applications/Xcode_11.2.1.app'
    packageApp: true
    exportOptions: 'plist'
    exportOptionsPlist: 'CICD/Info.plist'
    signingOption: 'manual'
    signingIdentity: '$(MY_CERTIFICATE_SIGN_IDENTITY)'
    provisioningProfileUuid: '$(MainTarget_ProfileUUID)'
    provisioningProfileName: '$(MainTarget_ProfileName)'
```

Let me know if I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to make it work with a simple way.

- compile your projet localy with XCode
- archive it and export it for your purpose (for me it was Testflight upload)
- in the folder you export .ipa, you will find an "export-options.plist"
- in the Pipeline Azure, XCode build Task specify this file in the : "export option plist"
  [image]

(you'll have to add the file in your repo and commit/push it)

and tada !
source that lead me there : https://blog.bitrise.io/new-export-options-plist-in-xcode-9

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is not a straight forward way for the iOS application with App extension in Azure.

1. To make it work you'll have to do a couple of changes in the project that are recommended on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29605731/3611427).
2. Afterward, you'll be able to build and archive the application using `xcodebuild` [Docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html) because you'll have a variable pointing to each provisioning profile.
3. On your MAC try **xocdebuild** command in the terminal and note down the full commands to achieve a specific file.
4. Use `CmdLine@2` task in the pipeline with these commands to build, archive & export your IPA.

> Note: I have posted a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/shakaib-arif/c648267883321c0231a771017212f93b) covering the pipeline for such an iOS application.

```
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  displayName: 'Install Certificates'
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: '3Certificates.p12'
    certPwd: '$(P12Password)'
    keychain: 'temp'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install MainTarget provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'MainTarget.mobileprovision'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install OneSignal provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'OneSignal.mobileprovision'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'CocoaPods install'
  inputs:
    script: |
      cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
      echo "Pod installation"
      pod install

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:    
    script: |
      echo "Build iOS app"
      cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
      
      /usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk $(sdkOption) -configuration $(configurationOption) -workspace $(workspaceName) -scheme "$(schemeName)" build -allowProvisioningUpdates CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$(signingIdentity)" APP_PROFILE="$(APP_PROFILE_ID)"  EXTENSION_PROFILE="$(APP_EXT_PROFILE_ID)"
  displayName: 'Xcode Buid'

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:    
    script: |
      echo "Archive the iOS app"
      cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
      
      /usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk $(sdkOption) -configuration $(configurationOption) -workspace $(workspaceName) -scheme "$(schemeName)" archive -allowProvisioningUpdates CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$(signingIdentity)" APP_PROFILE="$(APP_PROFILE_ID)"  EXTENSION_PROFILE="$(APP_EXT_PROFILE_ID)" -archivePath $(ArchivePath)
  displayName: 'Xcode Archive'

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:    
    script: |
      /usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $(ArchivePath) -exportOptionsPlist $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MyApplication-Info.plist  -exportPath $(ExportIpaPath)
  displayName: 'Xcode Export'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927823/can-we-configure-ci-for-ios-apps-with-extensions-with-azuredevops), you can try building the ios App in [command-line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) and pass the extension app name as a parameter.

Something like: `xcodebuild ... -scheme "YourExtension" -CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=xxx PROVISIONING_PROFILE=xxx CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=xxx`

For more details about how to build projects from the command line see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014588-CH1-HOW_DO_I_BUILD_MY_PROJECTS_FROM_THE_COMMAND_LINE_).

Comment: Hi @LanceLi-MSFT, I have tried the command line approach which you have suggested but it doesn't cater to the multiple provisioning profiles set up in the command. And I think this kind of iOS app's CI can only be achieved with command line as of now.

Comment: @Shakaib  Can [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29605731/10910450) makes some help for you? And since the official task doesn't suggest building ios app with extension, we can use CMD task/Bash task in CI pipeline to build the app.

Comment: Yes! that link is of good help to me and I have found it the other day. Thanks for sharing. Currently, I'm using the recommended configuration in my project suggested by **Max Chuquimia** and some other configuration along the way. I have successfully built the Xcode app using the **command line**. Will be posting my pipeline configuration once it's finalized.

Comment: Great, glad to know my answer makes some help. You could consider adding your solution as answer once it's finalized. See [can I](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)...